# What is the mathematical relationship in this sequence?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, sequence, sequences

I am working on a path planning algorithm, which returns the "path to the goal" as a sequence of numbers. I need to find which element (row and column) of my matrix these numbers correspond to. So I am looking for a mathematical expression that depicts the relationship.

The relationship is as follows:

```
1 --> row = 1 and column = 1
2 --> row = 1 and column = 2
3 --> row = 1 and column = 3
4 --> row = 1 and column = 4
.
.
.
37901 --> row = 1 and column = 37901
37902 --> row = 2 and column = 1
37903 --> row = 2 and column = 2
37904 --> row = 2 and column = 3
.
.
.
1436485801 --> row = 37901 and column = 37901
```

Note that 1436485801 = 37901^2, where 37901 = 151*251. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood this correctly. Are you trying to map the pair `row, column` to an 1D index? If so, shouldn't the last value `1436485801` be at row `37901` and column `37901`?

Comment: @Aziz I fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

To map `(row, column)` pair to a 1D index, you can use:

```
 index = column-size * (row - 1)  + column
```

So, in your case, it is

```
index = 37901 * (row - 1) + column
```

Matlab has the useful [**function `sub2ind`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) that does that for you.

```
// for a matrix A
index = sub2ind(size(A), row, column)
```

## **Edit:**

To perform the opposite operation, converting an 1D index to a row and column, you can use the **[function `ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html)** **(you MUST know the size of the matrix)**:

```
// for a matrix A
[row, column] = ind2sub(size(A), index)
```

Or, if you want to do it manually, the values are:

```
row    = fix((index-1)/size(A,1)) + 1; // quotient 
column = rem( index-1, size(A,1)) + 1; // remainder
```

Comment: row and column are the unknowns here. The algorithm returns the numbers in a sequence (e.g. 1, 2, 37903, 37904) and I am trying to find the row and column corresponding to every number in the returned sequence.

Comment: @canberk_gurel Do you know the size of the matrix?

Comment: It can be as large as 37901 by 37901

Comment: The question is not how large the matrix is, but if you know it's dimensions when calculating the row and number values.